# Increase the number of AJAX calls from a website

Tags: java, ajax, http, jakarta-ee, servlets

I want to increase the number of ajax calls that my website makes to my server running Java Servlets.
I am planning to send one request to a `MainServlet` and then that servlet sends multiple requests to `OtherServlets`.
What I want is that instead of `OtherServlets` returning their `response` to `MainServlet`, they should directly send `response` to the client.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Just `forward` the request from `MainServlet` to `OtherServlet`

Comment: can we forward the request to more than one servlet?

Comment: Once you forward request from one servelt to other servlet you could forward from otherservlet to new other servlet, but that doesn't look good, why don't you wrap logic in some good service and design one controller for these requests

Answer (score 0):

One way out be create many calls using javascript/Ajax. You can always create loops to make repeated calls to a Servlet using Ajax. Not sure what your objective is. You want to load-test your servlet of something else.